# AngularJS + Google Maps not showing Marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have a marker working fine on $scope.mapCreated. Now I am trying to show another marker when user clicks on $scope.centerOnMe() but only current location is displayed without the marker.

Do I have to use [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example) or is there an easiest solution?

**controller**

```
.controller('mapCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$ionicLoading', function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading){

$scope.mapCreated = function(map) {

    var latlngPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.4264356, -51.7838787);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlngPlace
    });

    $scope.map = map;
};

$scope.centerOnMe = function () {
console.log("Centering");
if (!$scope.map) {
  return;
}

$scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
  content: 'Wait...',
  showBackdrop: false
});

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
  console.log('Got pos', pos);

  $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));

    var myPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myPlace
    });


  $ionicLoading.hide();

}, function (error) {

    console.log('Error' + error.message)
});
};    

}])
```

directives.js

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])

.directive('map', function(){

return {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {
  onCreate: '&'
},
link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.426102, -51.784999),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], mapOptions);

    $scope.onCreate({map: map});

    // Stop the side bar from dragging when mousedown/tapdown on the map
    google.maps.event.addDomListener($element[0], 'mousedown', function (e)  {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    });
  }

  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    initialize();
  } else {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  }
}
}

});
```

map.html

```
<ion-view title="Map" id="page9" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
<ion-content>
    <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable bar-calm">
  <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate">FindMe</a>
</ion-footer-bar>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just missing the map: $scope.map

```
var myPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: $scope.map,
    position: myPlace
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new marker inside `centerOnMe()` function. Below is the sample which creates a new marker. Thats the only way to create a marker .

```
$scope.centerOnMe = function () {
  console.log("Centering");
  // Adding a new marker
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: $scope.map,
    position:  new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  });

  if (!$scope.map) {
     return;
  }
}
```

Comment: it did not work this way but thanks for showing the part of map: $scope.map